# How to enable AMD-NVIDIA switchable graphics for AMD APUs (Ryzen) ? (Especially on Muxless laptop)

Tags: amd-graphics, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I don't know why no one is talking about this. But, this is a problem I'm currently stuck at.
I have an laptop with AMD APU (Ryzen 5 - 2500U) & nvidia gtx 1050. This laptop is Muxless. This laptop's display is attached to the iGPU (Vega 8).

I want to use Vega for normal tasks. & Nvidia for process hungry tasks (mainly CUDA & ML training stuffs).

There are many (glitchy) options for switching graphics (e.g Prime, bumblebee) . But, everyone states about Intel-nvidia. If you search more, you can find some about intel-amd switching.

But, nothing for AMD-nvidia switching.

APUs are things. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Note : I can't disable any graphics on bios. My laptop doesn't allow it.

Laptop : Asus F570D

What I have tried : I tried installing ubuntu multiple times. It (almost) disappointed me everytime. The last time I did, it was ALMOST working correctly (by setting flags like - `noveau.modeset=0` ). It just sometimes freeze during boot forever.

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. (With the kernel it ships with)

Comment: once try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638289/use-opencl-on-amd-apu-but-use-discrete-gpu-for-the-x-server#36696650 . even I am thinking of building a system with AMD APU and NVIDIA GPU so I am also looking for issues like this, if this works please let me know

Comment: Almost everyone choose Intel as their main CPU architecture. To be honest, I hate Intel XD so inocently I was installing Bumblebee to achieve the dual graphic works but, for instance, the openSUSE documentation is so ambiguous and doesn't tell actually that is ONLY for Intel/nVidia. I installed the private nVidia drivers because many issues and I'm here, searching for the same.